# Subscribe to event handler inside Singleton class

Tags: c#, event-handling, singleton

I am trying to subscribe to an event inside Singleton class.

```
public class Singleton : IDisposable
{
    private static readonly Singleton _instance = new Singleton();
    public static Singleton Instance => _instance;

    static Singleton()
    {
        AppSettings.Instance.OnUpdated += OnAppSettingsUpdated;
        OnAppSettingsUpdated(null, null);
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        AppSettings.Instance.OnUpdated -= OnAppSettingsUpdated;
    }

    private static void OnAppSettingsUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    // do something
    }
}
```

`AppSettings` is another singleton class.

```
public partial class AppSettings
{
    public EventHandler OnUpdated;
}
```

When `OnUpdated` invoked, nothing happens. It looks like `OnAppSettingsUpdated` is not subscribed.

In a code I use `Singleton` like this.

```
Singleton instance = Singleton.Instance;
```

Maybe I missed something?
It is important to subscribe inside `Singleton` class.

Comment: A singleton class should not be declared `static`. A static class is one that you do not create instances of, while a singleton class is one that you create a single instance of. Generally speaking, the property that exposes the single instance should be the only static member of the class, where all members of a static class must be static.

Comment: With that in mind, the registration of the event handler should be in an instance constructor, not a static constructor.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, Sorry, `Singleton` is not `static`. I also tried to add handler to instance constructor, same result.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the issue is that you have never accessed the `Instance` property of your `Singleton` class. Until you actually use the class, none of the code within it will be executed, including static members. In order for your static field to be assigned and your static constructor to be run, you need to actually use the class somehow. Try assigning its `Instance` property to a variable somewhere and I think you'll find that your event handler will be executed when you expect it to be.

EDIT:

When I run this code, I see nothing in the console:

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Singleton2.Instance.RaiseSomethingHappened();
    }
}

public class Singleton1
{
    private static Singleton1 _instance = new Singleton1();

    public static Singleton1 Instance => _instance;

    private static void Singleton2_SomethingHappened(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Singleton2_SomethingHappened");
    }

    public Singleton1()
    {
        Singleton2.Instance.SomethingHappened += Singleton2_SomethingHappened;
    }
}

public class Singleton2
{
    private static Singleton2 _instance = new Singleton2();

    public static Singleton2 Instance => _instance;

    public event EventHandler SomethingHappened;

    protected virtual void OnSomethingHappened()
    {
        SomethingHappened?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public void RaiseSomethingHappened()
    {
        OnSomethingHappened();
    }
}
```

When I change this:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Singleton2.Instance.RaiseSomethingHappened();
}
```

to this:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var s1 = Singleton1.Instance;

    Singleton2.Instance.RaiseSomethingHappened();
}
```

and run the code again, I see the expected output in the console window. Either you're not actually using the single instance of the class handling the event or you're not registering the event handler correctly. This code demonstrates that the former makes a difference and how to do the latter.

Comment: I am using Singleton in code. So `Instance` is initialized.